# Example of function where f(x) is not surjective, g(x) is not injective and g º f is bijective.

Tags: functions

I am looking for the function of f(x) and g(x) that satisfies the conditions where f(x) is not surjective, g(x) is not injective and g º f is biyective. Here is my process of thinking: A non-surjective function does not have an input or x value to get a determined f(x) or output value. I used a function where x cannot satisfy f(x).

[image: formula]

A non-injective function is a function where there are two or more x values that satisfy f(x). I used a g(x) with this condition.

[image: formula]

This is where I get stuck, I don't know how to make these two biyective with g º f

Comment: Think of the images and codomains.  g isn't injective but fg is so f only maps to one "half" of the space but must map to all.  I figure we want:f:R ->(0,infty)injective.  Say f (x)=$e^x$.  Then we want g:R -> R where g ((0,infty)) =R.

Answer (score 5):

Map from a set with one point, to a set with two points, back to a set with one point.

Comment: Would [1]: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=f(x)%3DA%5Crightarrow%20B%5Cwedge%20C%2Cg(x)%3DB%5Cvee%20C%5Crightarrow%20D work?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x) = \arctan(x)$ and $g(x) = \tan(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $ f : \{0\} \to \mathbb{Z} $ defined as $ f(x) = 0 $.  And the function $ g : \mathbb{Z} \to \{0\} $  defined as $ g(x) = 0 $.

$f$ is not surjective, g is not injective but $ g \circ f $ is bijective.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints.

First, in order for the function $g \circ f$ to be bijective, the function $f$ must be injective. This means that the function $f$ cannot be

$$f(x) = x^2.$$

Second, the identity function is bijective. Try first thinking of a function $f$ which is injective but not surjective. Then try to think of a function $g$ such that $g \circ f$ is the identity function.